# AVC apparmor="DENIED" even after uinstalling Apparmor

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I am having conflict between MySQL and Apparmor, therefore I uninstalled Apparmor using:

```
sudo service apparmor stop
sudo service apparmor teardown
sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get remove apparmor
```

However, I can still see

```
 audit[9913]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
```

in journalctl output. My OS version is:

> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty
>   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
>
> Linux 4.10.0-32-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 12:10:06 UTC 2017
>   x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am at a loss here and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

The server required a restart after uninstalling AppArmor.

Comment: Had a similar problem and I also had to restart the server host...

Comment: One way to do this is `/etc/init.d/apparmor restart`